# SQL - Select Duplicates out of UNION ALL query

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, union-all

I am writing 4 queries using UNION ALL, and ordering them by field1.

```
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
FROM table1 

UNION ALL

SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
FROM table2 

UNION ALL


SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
FROM table3 

UNION ALL

SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4
FROM table4 

ORDER BY Field1
```

I want to return the rows only where field1 occurs twice.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, count(*) from (
    ... your query ...
)
GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
HAVING count(*)=2
```

(This is Oracle syntax, I hope this works with sql server as well).

Or, if you want all rows where Field1 occurs twice, but Field2, Field3 and Field4 may be the same or may be different:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 from (
    ... your query ...
) where Field1 in (
    SELECT Field1 from (
        SELECT Field1, count(*) from (
            ... your query ...
        )
        GROUP BY Field1
        HAVING count(*) = 2
    )
)
```

(Oracle syntax again).